How to move product-customization text fields after product-variants in Prestashop 8.1.5?
inside product.tpl there is the next code:
<div class="product-information">
                {block name='product_description_short'}
                    <div id="product-description-short-{$product.id}"
                          class="rte-content product-description">{$product.description_short nofilter}</div>
                {/block}

                {if $product.is_customizable && count($product.customizations.fields)}
                    {block name='product_customization'}
                        {include file="catalog/_partials/product-customization.tpl" customizations=$product.customizations}
                    {/block}
                {/if}

                <div class="product-actions js-product-actions">
                    {block name='product_buy'}
                        <form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post" id="add-to-cart-or-refresh">
                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product.id}"
                                   id="product_page_product_id">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_customization" value="{$product.id_customization}" id="product_customization_id" class="js-product-customization-id">

                            {block name='product_variants'}
                                {hook h='displayProductVariants' product=$product}
                                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
                            {/block}

                            {block name='product_pack'}
                                {if $packItems}
                                    <section class="product-pack">
                                        <p class="h4">{l s='This pack contains' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
                                        {foreach from=$packItems item="product_pack"}
                                            {block name='product_miniature'}
                                                {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/pack-product.tpl' product=$product_pack showPackProductsPrice=$product.show_price}
                                            {/block}
                                        {/foreach}
                                    </section>
                                {/if}
                            {/block}

                            {if $iqitTheme.pp_price_position == 'above-button'}
                                <div class="product_p_price_container">
                                {block name='product_prices'}
                                    {include file='catalog/_partials/product-prices.tpl'}
                                {/block}
                                </div>
                            {/if}

                            {block name='product_add_to_cart'}
                                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl'}
                            {/block}

                            {block name='product_discounts'}
                                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl'}
                            {/block}

                            {block name='product_refresh'}{/block}
                        </form>
                        {block name='product_additional_info'}
                            {include file='catalog/_partials/product-additional-info.tpl'}
                        {/block}
                    {/block}

I tried to move
 {if $product.is_customizable && count($product.customizations.fields)}
                    {block name='product_customization'}
                        {include file="catalog/_partials/product-customization.tpl" customizations=$product.customizations}
                    {/block}
                {/if}

after
{block name='product_variants'}
                                {hook h='displayProductVariants' product=$product}
                                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
                            {/block}

To see the product customization text fields after the attributes, but then, add to cart button keeps loading when i pressed it.
I tried to paste also the previous if part in different sides, but doesn't work. Always damage the add to cart button function.
Thank you very much in advance
